# Filling between two lines on plot

Tags: plotting, filling

Consider the plot

Plot[{x,x^2},{x,1,2}]

How to add a filling option such that the filling will be above x but below x^2?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark : thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Heck, I need the shiny points ... try adding the option `Filling -> {2}` like this

```
Plot[{x,x^2},{x,1,2}, Filling -> {2}]
```